# A translation into Latin of the very common English idiom ‘just in case’

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

This common English idiom means that you are doing something ‘just in case’ and
refers vaguely to the possibility that a thing might happen or be true, without saying exactly what it is but that you are taking preventative measures to avoid such a possibility.
-I don't think I'll need any money but I'll bring some just in case.
-Bring a map in case you get lost.
-The forecast didn't mention rain but I'm going to take an umbrella just in case.
Is there a Latin idiom or a good translation that members of the forum can suggest to match this English expression? Perhaps something on the lines of ‘ut omnia provideam’or ‘ne quid improvisi accidat’. However. I would appreciate any alternative or better translations.

Comment: Have you found it? I'm trying to find out thas for years. Anyway,  there's a similar question about  "in case of" the answers are pretty good.

Comment: At present, Manuel, I can find no better suggestions than the two I have suggested  above, of which I now prefer ‘ ne quid improvisi accidat’.

Answer (score -2):

We can use the conjunction "si"
"In case of war"
"Si quod extremum bellum exsitat"

Comment: I think the reason you got a couple downvotes (although I didn't vote myself yet) is because it's a pretty barebones answers. Do you think you could flesh this answer out a bit more, especially explaining why Latin would prefer a conditional instead of the adverbial "just in case"? I think you're on the right track, personally, but more explanation would be helpful to others evaluating this answer.